# How to edit XML column in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I would like to edit **XML** column which is displaying as *(XMLTYPE)* by **SQL Developer** editor (I go there by clicking on the field twice, edit, then save).

After that the displayed value changes to *sqldev.xml:/home/myuser/.sqldeveloper/tmp/XMLType8226206531089284015.xml*

```
Build after save retrieving next build context...

Build after save building project 1 of 1 queued projects

Compiling...
  Ignoring /home/username/.sqldeveloper/tmp/XMLType5691884284875805681.xml; not on source path
[11:45:33 AM] Compilation complete: 0 errors, 1 warnings.

Build after save finished
```

and when I try to commit:

```
UPDATE "USERNAME"."TABLENAME" SET  WHERE ROWID = 'AABWNKAAEAAABSbAAB' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '6951979'

One error saving changes to table "USERNAME"."TABLENAME":
Row 1: Illegal format in column NEXTCOLUMN.
```

I tried to look for this error and found people who also had it, but without the solution.
If you have an advice how to report it to Oracle, it will be also helpful.

Comment: Hi, Your update statement is not full , set what to what ?

Comment: @VBoka That's what SQL Developer shows in messages log. I don't understand why there is no column name/value (XML) which I'm trying to update - probably because of the previous warning.

Comment: Ok, it would be great if you can give us samle data : what you try to change to and from...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sampleTag1>
  <sampleTag2>
    value1
  </sampleTag2>
</sampleTag1>

I'm trying to change _value1_ to _value2_.

Comment: Please tag a  version of your oracle database ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will be of help to you:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET table_column=
   UPDATEXML(table_column,
   '/sampleTag1/sampleTag2/text()','value2')
   WHERE some_column = some value --<< this part is where you put your condition
```

Here is where you can find more about it:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm

**-------------------------**

If your problem is with editing through SQL developer manually via integrated editor then it is, as far as my testing and researching can tell, because of the **SQL Developer version**.

You have noted in your comment that you use version **4.1.x** and I have found few places where people confirm that they had the same problem with this version.

I also have 4.1.x version and I have also successfully repeated your error where the developer is referring to my `.xml` file in my `...\sqldeveloper\tmp` folder not being on it's source path :

> Compiling...   Ignoring C:\Users\trle\AppData\Roaming\SQL
>   Developer\tmp\XMLType6413036461637067751.xml; not on source path
>   [4:33:29 PM] Compilation complete: 0 errors, 1 warnings.

I have then downloaded version **19.2.x** where there is no such problem and all works just fine.

So my answer to your problem is to download some newer version of SQL developer. In my case 19.2. works.

**-------------------------**

**UPDATE** Just tested on version **4.2.x** - also works

Comment: Hi @Line , did you try to execute this query? Do you have questions?

Comment: Yes, it works. I don't have questions, yet this is not the answer to my problem. Rather workaround.

Comment: Hi @Line can you please tell me which version of SQL Developer do you use ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using 4.1.3.20.

Comment: Hi @Line I have updated my answer. Hope this will help you. Cheers!

Comment: you're right, it indeed works on 4.2 version. seems to be the bug which was fixed. thank you

Comment: Hi @Line, I am happy I have helped. Thank you kindly for your feedback. That is very nice. Cheers!